# OctoberCMS Plugin update url

Tags: octobercms

I am planning on making several custom / proprietary plugin for a project I'm developing.

Those plugin that I maintain will need to be able to update independently using OctoberCMS Plugin Updates mechanism, but because of various reasons, I will not
be registering those plugins in the ***marketplace***.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

#### Solution by `spunky` on freenode:

- Drop / symlink / or just place your plugin folder inside `~/plugin`, making sure that it's accessible by the server
- Logout of backend
- Log back in
- All db migrations and all other stuff should be handled by OctoberCMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

October CMS now (October 2019) supports private plugins and themes. These plugins will never show up in the marketplace but can be added to a project and thus be updated using OctoberCMS Plugin Updates mechanism.

For more information see:

- https://octobercms.com/blog/post/welcome-private-plugins-themes
- https://octobercms.com/blog/post/protected-mode-private-plugins-themes

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible. I understand what you want, but at the moment, this isn't possible.

But, you can try to make your own server, but as the OctoberCMS.COM server isn't open source, it will be very difficult.

The best way would be to install them manually.